# Windows Forms hotkeys than can be changed by the user

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-forms-designer

Recently I decided to try programming again (I had some experience with Python before, very little though) and I chose C# to play with. Currently I'm trying to develop an application where the user can change the hotkeys, and this is what I have:

```
void MainFormKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    object altTecla = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    object tecla = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    if(combobox1.SelectecIndex != 0){   //Index 0 = without 'alt', 'ctrl' or 'shift'
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.altTecla && e.KeyCode == Keys.tecla){
           //do something
        }
     } else {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.tecla{
           //do something
        }
     }
}
```

But I can't run that:

```
'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'tecla' (CS0117)
'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'tecla' (CS0117)
'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'altTecla' (CS0117)
```

Apparently it is not recognizing 'altTecla' and 'tecla' as variables, and I don't know which type 'altTecla' and 'tecla' should be.

I tried searching for similar posts but there isn't any.
What could I do to solve this?
Also, any other problems in the code? I suspect that the two last IF's will not work but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: What are tecla and altTecla supposed to be? They're definitely not a part of the Keys enum... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not to be rude or anything (because you're a beginner), but your code doing `Keys.altTecla` and `Keys.tecla` are just non-sense. You can't "add" an object to a enum.

Comment: @Broots Waymb `altTecla` is the current selected item in comboBox1, which holds the items 'alt', 'ctrl' and 'shift', and `tecla` is the current selected item in comboBox2, which holds the items 'F1' to 'F9', 'D1'(the 1 key) to 'D2'(the 2 key) and so on.

@Blake Thingstad Yeah, seems like I'll have to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use hotkeys in an application (or at least how I have done it before) is to import these functions (you put these lines of code in the same place as a property or field or method).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
// Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
// Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
// ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3
```

You can then use it like this...

```
RegisterHotKey(Handle, 1, 2, (int)Keys.T);
```

This will use the Handle from the form this is called in, give an Id of 1 (can have multiple different hotkeys, so give an Id to identify each one), and register it as Ctrl + T. Ctrl because the third param is 2.

The best way to go about this would be to Register and Unregister the hotkey in the SelectedIndexChanged event if the ComboBox contains different key options.

If you need any further help with this, I would be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that out

Comment: It worked! I mean, I had to add more heavy researching and more heavy work, but it worked. Many thanks.

Comment: @Pedro Awesome! Glad I could help